# audio node tapping microphone, gets called repeatedly only if there is a self.function inside

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I'm creating an FFT spectrum display which prints `signal[100]` over and over, however this only works if I call a function outside of the closure. Why is this?

```
func beginTappingMicrophone() {
    let inputNode = engine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    let bufferSize = 4096

    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize), format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) in
        let fft = PowerSpectrum.powerSpectrum(channelDataValueArray)

        self.emptyFunction()
        print(signal[100])
    }
}
```